# Margins overlap in side by side minipages

Tags: margins, minipage, exam

Trying to put two `minipages` side by side in the `exam`class, but the droppoints and part numbers are overlapping (see image).

I can't find any info anywhere on how to solve this/edit margin sizes within `minipage`. Any suggestions kindly welcomed!

Code used:

```
\begin{parts}
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
   \part[3]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (B) at (4,4);
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (5,0);
    \draw[very thick] (B) -- (A) -- (C);
    \draw[fill] (3,3.2) circle [radius=0.2];
    \draw [very thick, ->] (1,3.2) node [left] {$F$} -- (2.8,3.2);
    \draw [very thick, ->] (3,3.2) -- (3,2) node [below] {$10g$};
    \pic [draw,angle radius=1.5cm,"$45^\circ$" shift={(10mm,2mm)}] {angle=C--A--B};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \droppoints
 \end{minipage} 
 \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
   \part[3]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (B) at (4,4);
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (5,0);
    \draw[very thick] (B) -- (A) -- (C);
    \draw[fill] (3,3.2) circle [radius=0.2];
    \draw [very thick, ->] (1,3.2) node [left] {$F$} -- (2.8,3.2);
    \draw [very thick, ->] (3,3.2) -- (3,2) node [below] {$10g$};
    \pic [draw,angle radius=1.5cm,"$45^\circ$" shift={(10mm,2mm)}] {angle=C--A--B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \droppoints
\end{minipage}

\end{parts}
```

PS I know my code isn't the most concise but hopefully it's clear - any tips gratefully received!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please tell us which packages are loaded in the preamble of your document.

Comment: Please always provide a usable example, we can not run this code as posted. However your two minipages are 90% of the width but you have only put a word space between them if you used `\end{minipage}\hfill` after the first minipage they would be pushed further apart.

Comment: ```\hfill``` worked perfectly! Thank you. I'll be sure to add the minimum preamble in future posts.